# Grease monkey xpath and Firebug issues

Tags: xpath, firebug, greasemonkey

script:

From firebug xpath on the button is as follows:

```
.//*[@id='ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3']
```

and the script piece is:

```
<br>
    <input name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceholder$Button3" 
           value="Back To Auctions" 
           onclick="closePopup(); return false;"
           id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3" 
           class="simplemodal-close" 
           style="width:160px;" 
           type="submit">
<br>
```

My GM script is as follows:

```
// @include *
// @version     0.1
// @description Automatically click // ==/UserScript==

click_popupBtn1 = function() {

    var joinBtn=document.evaluate(
                  '//*[@id, "ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3"]',
                  document,
                  null,
                  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
                  null).singleNodeValue.click();
alert(joinBtn);
    if(!joinBtn) return false;
    joinBtn.click();
    return true;
}
```

click_popupBtn1 ();

I've discovered this auction site, which I want to automate with GM. There is two screen shots. www.mediafire.com/?lwy7agybtfn2x. The first screen shot is the basic overview of site, with bidding buttons. Second overview, winnings popup.

What I need to do: I need some help first to get rid of the popup. If it's there I can't bid. I used a similar script for the login page, and managed to get GM to auto login, because the server needs you to log in every three hrs or so. See above mentioned scripts and xpath. I've tried, but my gm script piece doesn't click on it.

Then the project: I would like to do some of it myself, but I need some pointers. on the attached txt file, auction1.txt, I've copied some of Firebug's console files, which look like :

```
GET http://www.xxx.xxx/REST_Service/REST_Auction.svc/GetAuctionData?_=1303059143094 
200 OK
29.62s   firebu...rver.js (line 169)
<System>
ParamsHeadersResponse {"d":[["","","y","ZAR","1","33713","8887, 8887, 8887, 8887, 8887",null,"1.26","8887","0:13:30","","12","","C","29",null],["","","y","ZAR","2","34029","",null,"0.76","NONE","0:10:37","","5","","L",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","3","30332","3616, 9390, 9841, 8664, 4901",null,"379.80","3616","0:01:09","","1100","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","4","33987","3616, 9168, 0605, 9168, 8771",null,"1.26","3616","0:00:51","","12","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","5","34030","",null,"0.76","NONE","0:12:28","","5","","L",null,null],["y","-00:00","y","ZAR","6","34028","1137, 1137, 1137, 1137",null,"2.64","1137","0:20:05","","12","","L","12","vkSaGLYmZD+vgphl90foiM+3QXDf0c7SRfpMnt9PSDw="],["","","y","ZAR","7","33938","3616, 3616",null,"5.60","3616","0:01:50","","55","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","8","33729","3616, 6197, 3616, 6197, 9134",null,"3.34","3616","0:01:26","","29","","T",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","9","33867","1551, 7243",null,"1.73","1551","0:02:40","","10","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","10","33293","1551, 7243, 7243, 7243, 7243",null,"3.43","1551","0:06:10","","10","","B",null,null],["","","y","ZAR","11","33174","7243, 4901, 3614, 0481, 0481",null,"3.71","7243","0:06:10","","10","","B",null,null]]}
GET http://www.xxx.xxx/REST_Service/REST_Auction.svc/GetAuctionData?_=1303059144766
```

From there I can see all the info I need, and it is updated each second, so in order for me to tell the GM script to bid on which button, I need to get that information into the script to be processed. Does anyone have any ideas?

I was thinking in the line of writing a small script for each of the 12 small auctions, each handling its own part, collecting its own info. I was thinking those responses from Firebug can be useful and more direct way of getting info, that to go and subtract them one by one from the windows, which is updated afterwards.

Comment: It looks like you have `ctl00$mainContentPlaceholder$Button3` instead of `ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3`...

Comment: @ alenjandro: the script in the page is: "<br>
    <input name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceholder$Button3" 
           value="Back To Auctions" 
           onclick="closePopup(); return false;"
           id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3" 
           class="simplemodal-close" 
           style="width:160px;" 
           type="submit">
<br>
" ,

Comment: But my gm script i hav as: "    var joinBtn=document.evaluate(
                  '//*[@id, "ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3"]',
                  document,
                  null,
                  XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
                  null).singleNodeValue.click();" where it is ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3, so im not sure if im right...

Answer (score 1):

Without taking a closer look at the code or more thoroughly reading through the whole post, this line jumps out at me: 
`'//*[@id, "ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3"]'`

I'm not 100% sure off the top of my head but I believe that should probably be:
`'//*[@id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_Button3"]'`

I strongly recommend using the [Firefinder for Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/) addon to help with creating your XPath paths :]

Secondly, take a look at the [Mozilla Developers Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) for generating click events (iirc, `joinBtn.click();` won't work within a Greasemonkey script).

Comment: @Brock Adams: Yes, he mentioned using Firebug, but _Firebug !== Firefinder_. I assume that he used the HTML tab of Firebug to obtain the XPath (maybe right-click on the node > copy XPath?), but this is different functionality to the _separate addon_ Firefinder. Firefinder is a separate addon which extends Firebug to provide extra functionality in an extra tab on the Firebug panel (Console|HTML|CSS|Script|DOM|Net[|Firefinder]).

Comment: Okay. I just saw that extension's description: `"Finds HTML elements matching chosen CSS selector(s) or XPath expression"`, and assumed the OP had that part covered.  But, I see now that the extension also might help test an XPath query.